# Replace all text except text in between double quotation marks? (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, regex

Hope everyone's well.

Was writing a short story, but halfway through I decided to change it into third person.

For example I would like to change:

> I looked at him blankly after finishing his mixtape and said, "Bro, Imma be honest with you. I think its trash."

to

> Pepe looked at him blankly after finishing his mixtape and said, "Bro, Imma be honest with you. I think its trash."

How do I go about replacing certain text without touching the same text that's in between the double quotation marks?

Hope I made sense & cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [`(*SKIP)` & `(*FAIL)` verbs](http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html).

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bI\b`
- Replace with: `Pepe`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  "[^"]+"           # every thing between a pair of quotes
  (*SKIP)           # skip that
  (*FAIL)           # and consider the match has failed
|                 # OR
  \bI\b             # liiterally I surrounded with word boundaries
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Sorry i took so long to get back to you, but thank you for this. 100% apprecaite you